# How to put notification badges on icons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get notification badges working and I'm almost there :)

It works nicely when I have the notification badges there but if I remove it, the Icon drops down for some reason and I can't figure out why.

[image]

```css
.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.icon-badge-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-badge-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-badge {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 35%;
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  left: 17px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon-badge-container">
    <i class="far fa-envelope icon-badge-icon"></i>
    <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-badge-container">
    <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
    <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-badge-group">
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
      <i class="far fa-envelope-open icon-badge-icon"></i>
      <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
      <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
      <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
      <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/badge/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did a really good job, only thing that needed to change was the position from `relative` to `absolute`. When changing this the badge stop interacting with other elements flows/layout-position and will become a kind of 'layer on top' of your `icon-badge-container` element.

The other inline-block element `icon-badge-container` won't be bother by your badge anymore.

I marked the CSS with a comment what lines are changed.

More about positions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
.icon-badge-group {
 
}

.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:15px;
}

.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container:first-child { 
  margin-left:0
}

.icon-badge-container {
    margin-top:20px;
    position:relative;
}

.icon-badge-icon {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.icon-badge {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius: 35%;
    position: absolute; /* changed */
    top: -5px; /* changed */
    left: 18px; /* changed */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">


<div class="icon-badge-group">
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
        <i class="far fa-envelope-open icon-badge-icon"></i>
        <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
        <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
        <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
        <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because this is a layout issue when working with display: block and display: inline-block etc. you can also learn more about display: flexbox. Some of the issues you can find are solved using the flexbox technics. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

> That's because of position `relative` just make it `absolute` so that
>   to its presence didn't effect icon

```css
.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.icon-badge-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon-badge-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-badge {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon-badge-container">
    <i class="far fa-envelope icon-badge-icon"></i>
    <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-badge-container">
    <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
    <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-badge-group">
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
      <i class="far fa-envelope-open icon-badge-icon"></i>
      <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
      <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-badge-container">
      <i class="far fa-user icon-badge-icon"></i>
      <div class="icon-badge">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more line css code, Something like that:

```
.icon-badge-group .icon-badge-container{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```